# Remove two first character of line if match (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file large with content format below, i want remove two first character 11, i try to search by dont know how to continue with my code. Looking for help. Thanks

file.txt

> 11112345,67890,12345
>
> 115432,a123q,hs1230
>
> 11s1a123,qw321,98765321
>
> 342342,121sa,12123243
>
> 11023456,sa123,d32acas2

My code

```
import re

with open('in.txt') as oldfile, open('out.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        removed = re.sub(r'11', '', line[:2]):
            newfile.write(removed)
```

Result expected:

> 112345,67890,12345
>
> 115432,a123q,hs1230
>
> s1a123,qw321,98765321
>
> 342342,121sa,12123243
>
> 023456,sa123,d32acas2

Comment: In your expected result, shoudn't the 2nd line be `5432,a123q,hs1230` ?

Comment: @LaurentH. actually my file have format 115432,a123q,hs1230 clue is after remove '11' all will have 6 character to first ',' thank you

Comment: OK, but this was not clear in your post. However you can use the additional condition `line[6] != ','` to avoid removing the '11' when it is not necessary.

Comment: I completed my answer. You can accept it if OK for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a suggestion of easy-to-read solution, without using regex that I find a bit cumbersome here (but this is obviously a personal opinion):

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as oldfile, open('out.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        newfile.write(line[2:] if line.startswith('11') else line)
```

*Added note after comments from @kng: you can use the additional condition `line[6] != ','` to avoid removing the '11' when there are only 6 characters before the comma.*

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is this line :

```
removed = re.sub(r'11', '', line[:2]):
```

Because in this case :

- You'll only write the 2 first character of the line in the file
- You'll replace each "11" by empty char

The answer provided above is great, even if it doesn't match you're 2 expectation (115432,a123q,hs1230)

However, if you definitely wants to use the regex :

```
removed = re.sub(r'^(11)','', line)
```

This line should work